# Changing RatingBar Size Programmatically?

Tags: android, view, ratingbar, android-viewgroup

Is there a way to change RatingBar Widget size , programmatically without using xml styles?

I know we can customize size of RatingBar using [xml styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18980892/5896744) , but it is still not generic enough , i seem to encounter some of good github libraries that achieve this goal but they are offering it for cost of API 15+ , my minSDK is 10 , so can anyone help identify solution to :

**Reduce size of ratingBar widget programmatically under api 10** ?

Answer (score 0):

This a long shot, but:

- If you are using only stars (no custom shapes).
- You are willing to use API 11+.

I made a library which might help you: [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

It features:

- Fully working `android:layout_width`: it can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or abritary dp.
- Arbitrary number of stars.
- Arbitrary step size.
- Size of stars can be controlled exactly or by setting a maximum size.
- Customizable colors in normal state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable colors in pressed state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable size separation between stars.
- Customizable border width of stars.
- Customizable stars corner radius.
- Allows to set OnRatingBarChangeListener
- Stars fill can be set to start from left to right or from right to left (RTL language support).
- AnimationBuilder integrated in the view to set rating programatically with animation.

[Here is a preview of it](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/raw/master/images/sample.gif).

To change the `width` you can change it as you would do with any other view ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343376/set-view-width-programmatically)). For example:

```
ratingBar.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
ratingBar.invalidate();
```

You can find it either in `jcenter` or in `Maven Central`. So in your `build.gradle` file just add to your dependencies:

`compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'`

I hope it's useful.